# My script only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, console, click

I have 2 options, bet1 and bet2. I hope I cant run twice every option but I am stuck. This script just run one on console.

```
if (stopMaxStake()) {
  return;
} else 
  higherBet();

console.log(realtime(time));
console.log('You LOST!');

multiply();

setTimeout(function() {
  $('bet' + i).trigger('click');
  if (i < 2) 
    f(i + 1);
}, getRandomWait());

//$loButton.trigger('click');
```

Comment: Sorry Lutfi, but you're going to need to provide a little more context before someone can help you.

Comment: I don't see `i` in scope?

Comment: hey , We need to have some more details in order to understand the context of some variables

Answer (score 0):

Check your iteration of "i"
we are not seeing any iteration going on except f(i+1)